# reversing string using stack in assembly, program freezes

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to write assembly code to reverse a string by passing it to the stack, then pop it back out using a loop.

I get  dlrow oll and then the program freezes. I can't figure out why. How do I fix this?

```
%include "io.mac"
.STACK 100H 
.DATA

    string     db 'Hello world'
    stringLen  equ $-string

   .CODE
        .STARTUP



mov ecx, stringLen
mov edx, ecx ;save string length
mov eax, string
mov esi, eax  ; esi points to start of string
add eax, ecx
mov edi, eax
dec edi       ; edi points to end of string
jz done       ; if string is 0 or 1 characters long, done
reverseLoop:
mov  al, [esi] ; load characters
mov ah,0
push ax
inc esi       ; adjusdt pointers
dec edi
dec ecx       ; and loop
jnz reverseLoop


done:
call reverseString
.EXIT

call reverseString

reverseString:
enter 0,0 ;save EBP

mov cx, dx


Lp1:
pop ax
mov ah,0
PutCh al
loop Lp1

  leave
  ret 8
```

Comment: You `push` stuff onto the stack then do a `call` which itself pushes the return address on the stack. Also, you do `ret 8`, why? Furthermore, specify intended environment, this is a mess of 16 and 32 bit code, hard to guess where you want to run it.

Comment: To be completely honest I wasn't sure what to make ret, so ret 8 was a guess.

Comment: Freezes where (which instruction)?  Use a debugger to find out.  Also, without any description of how you build and run this, it's not a [mcve]

Comment: Let me ask this then. Is loop and pop a valid way to do this?

Comment: Certainly. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is that you placed the popping in a subroutine! That way the return address stood in the way for correct popping of the characters.
This is a solution that doesn't use a subroutine, but still obeys what was asked:

```
    jcxz    Ready
    mov     dx, cx    ; Copy for latter
PushLoop:
    mov     al, [si]  ; load characters
    push    ax        ; Don't care about AH
    inc     si        ; adjust pointers
    dec     cx
    jnz     PushLoop
PopLoop:
    pop     ax
    PutCh   al        ; PutCh does not depend on AH
    dec     dx
    jnz     PopLoop
Ready:
    .EXIT
```

There's no need to use 32 bit registers (or else choose either 16-bit or 32-bit, but not a mix of both). Also you don't use the `EDI` register at all. Why then set it up?

---

An alternative would be to place all the code that reverses a string in a separate procedure and have it called passing the address and the length of the string on the stack.

```
    push    word stringLen
    push    word string
    call    ReverseString
    .EXIT

ReverseString:
    push    bp
    mov     bp, sp
    ... push any registers you need to preserve
    mov     cx, [bp+6]  ;2nd parameter is length
    jcxz    Ready
    mov     si, [bp+4]  ;1st parameter is address
  PushLoop:
    mov     al, [si]    ; load characters
    push    ax          ; Don't care about AH
    inc     si          ; adjust pointers
    dec     cx
    jnz     PushLoop
    mov     cx, [bp+6]  ;2nd parameter is length
  PopLoop:
    pop     ax
    PutCh   al          ; PutCh does not depend on AH
    dec     cx
    jnz     PopLoop
  Ready:
    ... pop any registers that you preserved
    pop     bp
    ret     4         ; Returns AND removes both parameters from the stack
```

Comment: One of things I was trying to do with this exercise was pass in parameters to a procedure via stack. That's why I was calling the procedure. How do I get around the return address and make it work with a procedure?

Comment: @Rubiks I've updated my answer with a solution that does `call` a subroutine and has parameters on the stack.

Comment: You went over and beyond, appreciate it